# MySQL GROUP BY and SUM values

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that containes the following data:

```
filer            time               name        size-percentage-used  disk-count
filer01a  2012-01-19 05:59:02  aggr0                     96               3
filer01a  2012-01-19 05:59:02  ncna01a_aggr01            97              42
filer01a  2012-01-19 05:59:02  ncna01a_aggr02            96              22
filer01a  2012-01-19 05:59:02  ncna01a_aggr03             0              22
filer01a  2012-01-19 12:00:01  aggr0                     96               3
filer01a  2012-01-19 12:00:01  ncna01a_aggr01            97              42
filer01a  2012-01-19 12:00:01  ncna01a_aggr02            96              22
filer01a  2012-01-19 12:00:01  ncna01a_aggr03             0              22
filer01a  2012-01-20 12:00:01  aggr0                     96               3
filer01a  2012-01-20 12:00:01  ncna01a_aggr01            97              42
filer01a  2012-01-20 12:00:01  ncna01a_aggr02            96              22
filer01a  2012-01-20 12:00:01  ncna01a_aggr03             0              22
filer01a  2012-01-21 12:00:01  aggr0                     96               3
filer01a  2012-01-21 12:00:01  ncna01a_aggr01            97              42
filer01a  2012-01-21 12:00:01  ncna01a_aggr02            96              22
filer01a  2012-01-21 12:00:01  ncna01a_aggr03             0              22
filer01a  2012-01-22 12:00:02  aggr0                     96               3
filer01a  2012-01-22 12:00:02  ncna01a_aggr01            97              42
filer01a  2012-01-22 12:00:02  ncna01a_aggr02            96              22
filer01a  2012-01-22 12:00:02  ncna01a_aggr03             9              22
...
```

The list of filers goes from 01 to 102 and time is updated daily. I need a query that will provide filer, sum(`disk-count`) as DDMs, size-percentage-used, and max(time).

The out put I'm looking for would be:

```
 filer    DDMs     size-percentage-used  time                
 ncna01a  89                         96  2012-01-19 05:59:02
 ncna01a  89                         96  2012-01-19 05:59:02
 ncna02a  89                         96  2012-01-19 05:59:02
 ...
```

I am a total MySQL newbie and any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you will need something like the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(disk-count) AS ddms, 
       AVG(size-percentage-used) AS percent_used, 
       MAX(time) as max_time 
FROM filers 
GROUP BY filer
```